# Spring Data JPA set column default value for a table which has no entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

my user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "USERID", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private boolean status;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name="USERSROLES",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USERID")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ROLEID")})
    private List<Role> roles;
```

role entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "ROLEID", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", nullable = false)
    private String roleId;

    @Column(name = "ROLENAME")
    private String rolename;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List <User> users;
```

But when I try the following:

```
    public User createUser(String pUsername, String pPassword, String pFirstname, String pLastname,
                           String pEmail, boolean pStatus, List<String> pRoles){

        User user = new User();
        List<Role> foundRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();

        pRoles.forEach(role -> {
            try {
                Optional<Role> foundRole = roleRepository.findRoleByRolename(role);
                foundRoles.add(foundRole.get());
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("During creating user: " + pUsername + " the role: " + role + " wasn't found.");
            }
        });

        user.setUsername(pUsername);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(pPassword));
        user.setFirstname(pFirstname);
        user.setLastname(pLastname);
        user.setEmail(pEmail);
        user.setStatus(pStatus);
        user.setRoles(foundRoles);

        userRepository.save(user);

        return user;
    }
```

Then I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'USERSROLEID' doesn't have a default value
```

What definitly is right, but how to solve it? Is there a way to set a default value for a column in a table which has no entity? I also tried to create a entity for the table and set the default value but with the same result.

Greetings,
algorithm

Comment: On which table is that column? And for what is it used?

Comment: The USERSROLEID column is in the USERSROLES table and it is the primary key of this table, the table has also two more columns which are: ROLE_ID, USER_ID both are foreign keys. The column ROLE_ID is the primary key of the table ROLES, which has the following columns: ROLEID, ROLENAME. The column USER_ID column is the primary key of the table of the table USERS, which has the following columns: USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, STATUS.

Comment: But why does the USERSROLES have an extra primary key? in a many-to-many table the PK is the combination of the two FK

Comment: Thanks I didnt knew that. But now it works!

Comment: Please add this as the answer or delete the question that it no longer appears as unanswered